# Asus Splendid Imitation with Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I'm using Asus laptop with Asus so called "ACVT" - ASUS Splendid Video Enhancement Technology tool. One of its futures is to enable "Eye Care" mode with 5 different levels(1-5, 5 is the maximum). I couldn't find exactly how is it really works, but found out in the following link that it reduces blue for about 30%:

https://www.asus.com/uk/ASUS-software-and-technology/

Basically, I want to implement this kind of effect in Photoshop, but seems like reducing only blue doesn't imitate the effect. Perhaps I'm not doing it right and you could suggest a right way of doing so(I used Curves for this).

It's also difficult to understand this effect as you can't catch it with screen capture tools - it capture the unfiltered image.

But this ACVT does affect white(#ffffff) for more kind of yellow, I can't say for sure.

Perhaps anyone here know what am I talking about and can help me with, please?

Comment: That link of yours shows **multiple** correction options. There's no way to know which one you may specifically be asking about. And Photoshop does have several `Image > Adjustment >` options to explore.

Comment: So you are asking how to reduce blue in your image but not "yellow" your white? Or are you asking how to to reduce blue on your monitor without "yellowing" your whites?